# Keep getting error even if I have Access-Control-Allow-Origin on my site

Tags: xmlhttprequest, access-control

I have this line on top of my PHP file (on line 3 to be exact): `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Then, at the bottom of the PHP file I have this `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var coordinates_latitude = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(6);
var coordinates_longitude = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(6);
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open('GET', 'http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.8/?lat=' + coordinates_latitude + ';lon=' + coordinates_longitude, false); 
req.send();
if(req.status == 200) {
    alert(req.responseText);
}
```

`position` is my GPS position which I call through HTML5. Now to my problem. I'm keep getting the following error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.8/?lat=59.378217;lon=13.504219. Origin http://localhost:8081 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

According to dozens of website I found when I Googled my problem, including this site with many accepted answers, this is the correct solution. But for me it does not work! I'm going crazy! What's wrong with this code?

Note: I have tested `IfModule` and that kind of things in `.htaccess`. Does not work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `access-control-allow-origin` on *your* site allows other sites to call your site.

What you need is to add this header to the site you are reading information form ("api.yr.no" in your case). If you have no control over this site iether check with owners if adding such header would be possible by owners or go with server side proxy approach.

Comment: Oh! So `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not client based so to speak. That explains it all :) Thanks!